# Repeating timer every 30 days

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a countdown timer on [codepen](https://codepen.io/neyriks/pen/eYRzLLp)

What do I need to change or add so that the timer repeats every 30 days?

Probably need to change here?

```
const end = new Date(2021, 8, 15, 13, 0,12, 12);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably convert the date to a unix epoch timestamp and do the following:

```
let remaining_time = the_timestamp % (2592000000 + offset)
```

Where 2592000000 is the length of 30 days in milliseconds and offset is the offset you desire (if any). Thus it will repeat every 30 days.